# Regex expression in vue.js for phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vue-component, regex-group

I want to make a regex for a user to make only this kind of pattern. Users can enter only 10 digits. I am trying this in Vue.js with this pattern. But this is not working its shows an error on the browser. I think we can not use '?' in vue.js.
can anyone tell me this kind of pattern without using '?'.

error: `vue.min.js:6 SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?d{3})?[-s]?d{3}[-s]?d{4}$/: Invalid group`

the pattern that I want to allow

```
123 123 1234

(123) 123 1234

(123)-123-1234

123-123-1234

1231231231
```

This is the vue.js code

```
<div v-if="DisplayForSchool">
   <validation-provider v-bind:rules="{ required: true, regex: /^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$/ }" v-slot="{ errors }" >
     <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
     <input name="Phone Number" v-model="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel">
     <span class="error--text">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
   </validation-provider>
</div>
```

Comment: "_..it shows an error on the browser..._" and where is the error? also show your actual code snipppet

Comment: works okay - https://regexr.com/5jrd6

Comment: I edited the code, can you check @Tibebes.M

Comment: `/^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$/` is fine. you must be doing something else wrong.. like removing the backward-slashes `"\"`, maybe?

Comment: To prove that your snippet works, [Try it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/tibebes/pen/ExgpjQj)

Comment: @Tibebes. M I don't know what's the problem with this I Tried to change the browser but still having the same problem.

Comment: doesn't the codepen I've shared work as well?

Comment: @Tibebes.M, I believe they don't want the validation error to kick in until you've finished typing. Which means `123-123-123` should pass, even though it's missing the last digit. Same for `123`. I might be wrong and OP should clarify it. If I'm right, the validation should probably not be triggered in real time, but only on form submission or maybe on blur event

Comment: @Tibebes.M I changed the way of regex like regex: /^[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[- ]?[0-9]{3}[- ]?[0-9]{4}$/ } its working.